# ffmpeg XDCAM HD vtag profiles

Tags: ffmpeg, profile

Hey guys sorry for disturbing you again, but these days I have a lot of work to do with ffmpeg. I found on http://code.google.com/p/ffmbc/wiki/XDCAMHD422Encoding vtag settings for XDCAM HD 422 and used them in my script, everything works fine for HD 422, now I am desperately searching for normal HD vtags and have found only one so far was `xd3v` for Apple XDCAM HD 1080i50 (35 Mb/s VBR) which I don't need because its interlaced. What I need are the vtags for 1080p24, 1080p25 and 1080p30. Here is the script I have found and adapted a bit:

`ffmpeg -threads "4" -i "$2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vtag xdv3 -vcodec mpeg2video -r 25 -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -dc 10 -intra_vlc 1 -non_linear_quant 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 3 -lmin '1*QP2LAMBDA' -rc_max_vbv_use 1 -rc_min_vbv_use 1 -b 35000k -minrate 35000k -maxrate 35000k -bufsize 36408333 -bf 2 -aspect 16:9 -acodec pcm_s16be -vf scale=${FC_PARAM_width}:${FC_PARAM_height} "$3"`

If there are any other mistakes in the script, please correct me :)

Answer (score 1):

What is a "normal HD vtag"? For the formats you want these are the vtags:

`xd5d XDCAM HD422 1080p24 CBR

xd5e  XDCAM HD422 1080p25 CBR

xd5f  XDCAM HD422 1080p30 CBR

xdv6  XDCAM HD 1080p24 VBR

xdv7  XDCAM HD 1080p25 VBR

xdv8  XDCAM HD 1080p30 VBR

xd55  XDCAM HD422 720p25 CBR

xd59  XDCAM HD422 720p60 CBR`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but it seems that there is a difference between XDCAM HD422 and XDCAM HD only. You see in my previous post I said that I used `xdv3`for HD only and I got **Apple XDCAM HD (not HD 422) 1080i50 (35 Mb/s VBR)** and I was searching for the other HD only vtags (if they exist)

Comment: @sebastian Okay I added the other ones in. I did not understand your query at first. But these are VBR.

Comment: first of all thank you very much, you were a great help. I have one last question left, do you seem to know the vtags for **XDCAM HD422 720p25 CBR** and **XDCAM HD422 720p30 CBR** too? These two would be the last missing vtags I need to know.

Comment: @sebastian Added those as well.

Comment: Thanks, but something gives me a headache. I used those presets for 720p25 and 720p30 and I can perfectly transcode my testclips, but the output is just sound and a green screen. Code looks like this `ffmpeg -threads "4" -i "$2" -pix_fmt yuv422p -vcodec mpeg2video -r 25 -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -dc 10 -intra_vlc 1 -non_linear_quant 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 3 -lmin '1*QP2LAMBDA' -vtag xd55 -rc_max_vbv_use 1 -rc_min_vbv_use 1 -b 50000k -minrate 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 36408333 -bf 2 -aspect 16:9 -acodec pcm_s16be -vf scale=${FC_PARAM_width}:${FC_PARAM_height} "$3"` where did I go wrong?

Comment: Sorry for double post but I had no characters left. I used VideoSpec (something similar like Mediainfo) and it said as format xd55 while using xd59 it gives me as format **Apple XDCAM HD422 720p60 (50 Mb/s CBR)** instead of HD422 720p30.

Comment: Inside libavformat also it is documented as 720p60. I never used it, just assumed it meant 30 fps but my bad. But you are not mentioning input file size/aspect. You are passing what to FC_PARAM_width/height? Why are you scaling? I'm afraid you have to give more details. Where/which player is showing green? Could scale be conflicting at the end after passing aspect? Too many variables to answer sensibly.

Comment: Edited it to `XDCAM HD422 720p60`, as per documented formats. It also says the same thing in ffmbc documentation and elsewhere.

Comment: We figured out that it would be way too much work for us to write a script for those 720p formats, thats why we won't need them anymore, but thanks anyways for trying to help me. Case closed!